# IActionResult The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: asp.net-core, generics, actionresult

I have an action wrapper method for my ASP.NET CORE web api

```cs
        public async Task<TResponse> ThrowIfNullActionWrapper<TResponse>(Func<Task<TResponse>> func)
            where TResponse : IActionResult
        {
            try
            {
                // business logic
                return await func();
            }
            catch (ValueNullCheckFailureException)
            {
                return (TResponse)(Object)new NotFoundResult();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

When I have different return types like below, I got `The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage` error.

```cs
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<MyDto>> Get(Guid id)
        {
            return await ThrowIfNullActionWrapper(async () => { 
                // some codes...
                if (xxxxx)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                // some codes...
                return Ok(dto);
            });
        }
```

If I remove the line `return NotFound();`, the error will go away.

It seems the different return types of `OK()` and `NotFound()` methods caused this issue. But both of them inherits from `IActionResult`.

Can I use `OK()` and `NotFound()` methods at same time without the `type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage` issue?

Comment: Just add `as IActionResult` to both `return` statements

Comment: @haim770 The return type of action method is `ActionResult<MyDto>`, which caused an error about implicit cast from `IActionResult` to `ActionResult<MyDto>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could add as StatusCodeResult after the  NotFound() method to avoid different return type for ThrowIfNullActionWrapper.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<RouteModel>> Get(Guid id)
    {
        return await ThrowIfNullActionWrapper(async () => {
            // some codes...
            if (1 == 0 )
            {
                return NotFound() as StatusCodeResult;
            }
            // some codes...
            return  Ok()  ;
        });
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: In my code, the final return type is `Ok(dto)`, which is a `OkObjectResult` and conflicts with `StatusCodeResult`. If I use `as ActionResult`, it will work. The `ActionResult` is the common parent abstract class of `OkObjectResult` and `BadRequestResult`. But why the abstract class `ActionResult` works and the inferface `IActionResult` doesn't work?